# Do I need to check if the object is null before a dispose() command?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

I have an object, for example `HttpWebResponse` ,that implements `IDisposable`, and therefore should be disposed.

Having this:

```
HttpWebResponse a = ....;
```

What will be the correct way of handling the object?

```
a.Dispose();
```

Or:

```
if (a!= null)
    a.Dispose();
```

Should I even care if the object is null? Can't I just Dispose it anyway?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's generally recommend to wrap anything which implements `IDisposable` with the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement

```
using (var a = new HttpWebResponse(...))
{
}
```

It's the equivalent of writing

```
var a = new HttpWebResponse(...);
try
{
   // use a
}
finally
{
    if (a != null)
        a.Dispose();
}
```

> Should I even care if the object is null? Can't I just Dispose of it anyway

Well no, because if you attempt to call `Dispose` on a `null` object the application will throw a `NullReferenceException`. Given your circumstance where you feel the `using` statement isn't a valid option another neat of way tidying this up is to write an extension method e.g.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void SafeDispose(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
            obj.Dispose();
    }
}
...
var a = new ...;
a.SafeDispose();
```

This then *would* allow you to call the method on a null object.

Comment: It was a general example.. there are many objects. I know about the using statement, I'm asking specifically about the null check. Won't use it on HttpWebResponse.

Comment: Tnx for the edit! cleared it up.. I know I should use Dispose() cos it's IDisposable and all, but why just setting a=null won't work? If it can't dispose a null, means, it doesn't exist, means it got the job done. no?

Comment: Btw, I will accept your answer in 3mins :) Doesn't allow me yet

Comment: @user990635 setting an object to `null` is not the same as calling `Dispose` on an object. Think about it this way, say your object internally created a `FileStream` and you clean up that stream in the `Dispose` call. If you set the disposable object to `null` *before* calling `Dispose` you are removing any reference to it and as a result introducing a memory leak (the file stream won't be freed until the application is closed). The GC **will not** call `Dispose` on your object for you.

Comment: Just another clarification.  The dispose method of the class should release any resources (file handles, bitmaps etc.) that the class created.  Setting an object to null only sets up the object for future garbage collection.  The resources are still being held.

Comment: @BradBruce I kind of explained that in my previous comment.

Comment: I prefer to use a `Zap<T>(ref T it) where T:IDisposable` method, which will `Interlock.Exchange` its parameter with `null` before disposal.  I figure that since such a method should generally only be called once on an object, the time penalty for calling `Dispose` should be pretty slight.

Answer (score 0):

You can now simplify the null check, as of C# 6.0, by using the null-conditional operator `?.`

```
var a = new HttpWebResponse(...);
try
{
    // use a
}
finally
{
    a?.Dispose();
}
```

References: [C# Language Reference: Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Answer (score -1):

first check if it's not null then dispose, else you will get an exception ofcourse.

Comment: Hmm.. so basically a.Dispose() is kinda equivalent to a=null?!

Comment: first check is it is no null and then dispose otherwise you get a execption because you want to free something want doesn't excit annymore

Comment: @user990635 `Dispose` **is not** the equivalent to `a = null`.

Comment: @user990635: The purpose of `Dispose` is to let an object know that it's no longer needed, in case the object knows of any actions that should be performed sometime within the lifetime of the universe (if not sooner), and which nobody else is going to have the information and impetus necessary to perform.  If an `IDisposable` object were abandoned without performing such actions, they might never get done.  A common example is an object which asks some outside entity for exclusive use of a resource and receives some sort of handle or token associated with that resource.

Comment: @user990635: The outside entity won't release the resource unless someone *with the token* asks that it be released.  If the only thing outside the entity with a copy of the token gets destroyed without having asked the entity to release it, the entity may continue to deny everyone else access to the resource.  While there are some "fallback" mechanisms that try to minimize problems caused by such things, it's better to let objects know when they're no longer needed, before they are abandoned.

Comment: "else you will get an exception ofcourse." - theres no reason why it should be so obvious. Delphi provides "Free" which is allowed to be called on a null object. It does a null check on "sender", and proceeds to call Destroy()